# VBA Excel - add userform textbox value to worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform, bookmarks

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()

'----------The Script below writes values to Word Doc ----------------------------------------

Dim wApp As Object
Dim wDoc As Object

'We need to continue through errors since if Word isn't
'open the GetObject line will give an error

'On Error Resume Next
Set wApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")


'We've tried to get Word but if it's nothing then it isn't open
If wApp Is Nothing Then
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

'It's good practice to reset error warnings
On Error GoTo 0

'Open your document and ensure its visible and activate after opening

Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\Documents\example.docx ", ReadOnly:=False)
    With wDoc
    .Bookmarks("bookmark1").Range.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value 'how do I also insert the TextBox1.Value to the next empty row in worksheet?

'so far I got this to do it but everytime i click submit it puts it in the same cell instead of the next row

Sheet6.Range("H2").Value = Me.TextBox6.Value

    End With

wApp.Visible = True

'set default file name and file path

ProposedFileName = Format(Now(), "DDMMMYYYY") & TextBox1.Value & "-" & ".doc"
ProposedFilePath = "C:\Documents\"

    With wApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    wDoc.SaveAs2 ProposedFilePath & ProposedFileName, _
    FilterIndex = 1, _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument

End With
End Sub
```

Hi all,

The code above is just a part of my script which works fine when the userform textbox value gets inserted to bookmark1 in word doc, but how do I also insert this textbox value to worksheet row for example goes under column header "name"?

Thank you.

Comment: This code is from Userform?

Comment: @NELMVN yes it is

Comment: `range.cells(C, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value`

Comment: @NELMVN would it be something like this code?

Comment: Can you post the your whole Code

Comment: @NELMVN I have now added the whole code

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to solve it by adding the code

```
Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets(2)

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finds the last blank row

ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = TextBox1.Value 'Adds the TextBox1 into Col A & Last Blank Row
```